# Can't load files using system.file or file.path in R?

Tags: r

I am using a program that requires me to load a "sam" file. However, the code given does not create the `data.file` variable necessary and instead produces `""`, a blank instead.

This is the code given:

```
data.file <- system.file(file.path('extdata', 'vignette-sam.txt'), package='flipflop')
```

I put in:

```
data.file <- system.file(file.path("Users", "User1", "Desktop", "Cond_18", 
                                   "Sorted_bam_files", "Cond_18_1.bam_sorted.sam"), 
                         package='flipflop')
```

The path is definitely correct and the package name is `flipflop`. However every time I check what the variable `data.file` is, it produces `""`. So the file is never being loaded and the script can't run.

I also put in the entire file path into one version of it:

```
data.file <- system.file('/Users/User1/Desktop/Cond_18/Sorted_bam_files/DBM_18_1.bam_sorted.sam', 
                         package='flipflop')
```

That version does not include `file.path`, but it is one of the script examples.

The line in the code that uses these variables is this:

```
if(preprocess.instance==''){
  print('PRE-PROCESSING sam file ....')
  data.file <- path.expand(path=data.file) # In case there is a '~' in the input path
  if(data.file==''){ print('Did you forget to give a SAM file?') ; return(NULL) } 
  annot.file   <- path.expand(path=annot.file)
  samples.file <- path.expand(path=samples.file)
```

And since data.file is `""` it defaults to `NULL`.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what `system.file` is used for.  From the help file: "Finds the full file names of files in packages etc".  Is the file you're looking for actually from the flipflop package or is it just a file on your system?

Comment: `system.file` is used to construct a call relative to the base directory of a package within your library in a platform-independent way, e.g. `read.csv(system.file('misc', 'exDIF.csv', package = 'utils'))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use `system.file` when the file you want to reference is from a package.  Here is what the help file for `system.file` says:

> Finds the full file names of files in packages etc.

You just want to reference a file on your machine. You can just directly store the path and use that as your data.file

```
data.file <- "C:/path/to/your/file"
```

The script uses `file.path` because it's a safer way to generate paths in a platform-independent way. For example:

```
> file.path("C:", "Users", "BotsRule", "Code", "myawesomeRscript.R")
[1] "C:/Users/BotsRule/Code/myawesomeRscript.R"
```

So the solution to your problem is to just make sure you're actually doing *something* just *anything* to correctly specify the path to your file.

Comment: Thanks so much! The examples in the manual only had system.file as the available method to load a file but just making data.file the direct path to the file was so much easier and it worked!

Comment: @L.Li The examples can only use files that the package installed so it *needs* to use system.file to be able to locate those example files.